# Set all images name of a product to the same field in other table separated by comma in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using MariaDB v10.1.31. I have 2 tables:

Product_images (created from a *.csv* import).

```
product_reference | name

REF.001           | example_image_1.jpg   
REF.001           | example_image_2.jpg
```

Importer* (created to store all the data I need from others tables).

```
sku     | images

REF.001 | null
```

How could I update **Importer** to show the following?

```
sku     | images

REF.001 | example_image_1.jpg,example_image_2.jpg
```

*Data in **Importer** would be to export in .csv and be able to import in WooComerce, this is why I need to import the images by this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
UPDATE importer 
JOIN (
    SELECT product_reference, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name
    FROM Product_images 
    GROUP BY product_reference
) pi ON importer.sku= pi.product_reference
SET importer.images = pi.name;
```

I should mention though, that your schema design may not be the best, depending on what you want to do. Read about [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms), if you don't know what that is. A OLTP database usually is in at least 3rd normal form. Comma separated values violate the 1st normal form already.

Comment: Yes, I know that isnt correct, but I need to store images by this way to import in WooComerce https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-column-header-reference/#section-1

Comment: Not to mention the table names!  Also: no need to create a table for WooComerce (WooCommerce?),  a view would be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26b804/14 for a solution for MySQL:

```
set @rc = 0;
set @pik = 0;
set @pin = '';

select t1ikey, max(npin) from (
 select *,
  @pik,
  if(@pik=t1ikey, (@rc := @rc + 1), (@rc := 1)) rn,
  if(@pik=t1ikey, @pin := concat(@pin,',',t1image), @pin := t1image) npin,
  (@pik := t1ikey) npik
  from t1
  order by t1ikey) i
group by t1ikey
```

giving:

```
t1ikey      max(npin)
1   firstimageofone.jpg,secondimageofone.jpg
2   firstimageoftwo.jpg,secondimageoftwo.jpg,thirdimageoftwo.jpg
3   firstandonlyimageofthree.jpg
```

MariaDB has "GROUP_CONCAT", which makes this a lot easier.

```
select t1ikey, group_concat(t1image)
  from t1
  group by t1ikey;
```

Comment: MySQL has that as well.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It fails: `#1146 - Table 'my_table_name.t1' doesnt exist`

Comment: But what did you say to phpMyAdmin first?  Replace my table and column names with yours.